# statsmodels.MSTL. What's wrong with the data

Tags: python, statsmodels

Creating  df for MSTL from the available data:

```
start = df_raw_data.loc[0,'DATE']
per= len(df_raw_data['DATE'])
index = pd.date_range(start = start, periods= per, freq = 'H')
east = df_raw_data['HAE_TCOMP'].tolist()
df_east = pd.DataFrame(east, index = index, columns =['East'])
```

print(df_east):

```
                        East
2021-08-12 22:00:00   63.741
2021-08-12 23:00:00   63.828
2021-08-13 00:00:00   63.930
2021-08-13 01:00:00   64.043
2021-08-13 02:00:00   64.127
...                      ...
2023-08-15 19:00:00  106.049
2023-08-15 20:00:00  106.155
2023-08-15 21:00:00  106.162
2023-08-15 22:00:00  106.151
2023-08-15 23:00:00  106.712

[17594 rows x 1 columns]
```

full df_east:

```
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/6Uw3awxOm-jp0A
```

df_east has no Nan and the time grid is regular but after:

```
east_mstl = MSTL(df_east['East'], #I tried just df_east without the column name
                 periods= [12
                           ,24
#                            ,4380
#                            ,8760
                           ]
                #  ,stl_kwargs={"seasonal_deg": 0}
               )
print(east_mstl)
```

I have

```
MSTL(endog, periods=[12, 24], windows=(11, 15), lmbda=None, iterate=2)
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
         ..
17589   NaN
17590   NaN
17591   NaN
17592   NaN
17593   NaN
Name: observed_east, Length: 17594, dtype: float64
```

What's wrong with the data or maybe there is a problem in setting the periods?